# How to make reverse array work with for loop only

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can reverse loop using for loop and pop/shift BUT I want to reverse an array with the help of for loop only.
So I tried,

```
let array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
function reverseArray(array){
    for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++){
        let temp = array[i];
        array[(array.length-1)-i] = array[i];
        array[i] = temp;
        //[ array[i], array[(array.length-1)-i] ] = [ array[(array.length-1)-i], array[i] ]
    }
    console.log(array)
}

reverseArray(array);
```

You can also see the destructuring method used in the comment, it also dont work.
I want to use in place array only, dont want to create another array for storage.
But I am not getting reversed string, can you please point out my mistake?

Comment: Initialize a new array. Have your for loop start at the end of your array. Append this value. Decrement with i--

Comment: Please see [What is the most efficient way to reverse an array in Javascript?](/q/5276953/4642212).

Comment: the key question to ask yourself: let array length be 10, how many swaps do I need?

Comment: @gog thanks, I will try that approach first before looking other answers